# PyQt5 event filter occassionally not gaining focus when window is deactivated

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to create a customizedwindow such that whenever window is deactivated.
The window becomes the 'active' window and regains the focus to the window

Below code is sort of working but randomly stops making the window 'active' after several window
deactivates, when this happens the app just blinks on the bottom of the toolbar or is just highlighted.

(Btw im using windows 7 if it matters)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys

class myWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        self.counter = 0

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowDeactivate:
            self.counter += 1
            print(self.counter)
            
            self.raise_()
            self.activateWindow()
            return False
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = myWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better implementation using win32gui and win32com.client, I think it depends on which os you're using since the previous (while loop implementation) wasnt working with windows 10. Had this working for several pc's now

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys
import win32gui
import win32com.client

class myWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        self.counter = 0

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.WindowDeactivate:
            if not self.isActiveWindow():
                self.refocus_window()
            return False
        return False

    def refocus_window():
        try:
            hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Repair')
            win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, 9)
            shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
            shell.SendKeys('%')
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
        except Exception as err:
            raise err



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = myWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```